# How to add another value to a dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I've finally finished my little side project of creating a dropdown that changes what's on the page based on your picked choice. Now i'm wondering if it's possible to add more variables that also get changed based on what is selected from the dropdown without having to rewrite too much code.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
require("regenerator-runtime/runtime");

const App = () => {
    const [hero, selectedHero] = useState(
        'Select a Hero'
    );
    const handleChange = event => selectedHero(event.target.value);
    return(
        <HeroSelect heroSelect={hero} onChangeHeadline={handleChange} />
    );

};
const HeroSelect = ({heroSelect, onChangeHeadline}) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({heroes: []});
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await axios(
                'https://api.opendota.com/api/heroStats',
            );
            setData({...data, heroes: result.data});
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{heroSelect}</h1>
            <select value={heroSelect} onChange={onChangeHeadline} >
                {data.heroes.map(item => (
                    <option>
                        {item.localized_name}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>
        </div>
    )
};
export default App
```

Comment: You can always add more variables and update the values based on what is selected in the dropdown. `useEffect` is one hook that can be used which will allow you to update the attributes based on the selected value

Comment: I don't think it's clear what you're asking. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I''m sorry it's hard for me to articulate. In the opendota API there is more information that I'm pulling then just Hero. There is a few other things. I want to be able to also display those based on what hero you select. Since I already fetched them from the website I didn't know how to also add those.